Can I write/extract data to the Timescale in MS Project?
I cannot seem to figure out how to extract/write to the Timescale in task usage view.
I can't seem to extract the data from here nor can I write to it.
I've got a timesheet data from employees, and I don't want to manually input the hours across over 1000 tasks.
I've spent about 2-3 days trying to figure out how to extract/add data to this field in microsoft project and just cannot seem to work it out.
I've tried to hunt down the documentation for help and I've review the VBA code and I feel like my code is right but I still can't get this to work.
Timescale
    import pythoncom
    import win32com.client

    # Initialize COM connection
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()

    # Create an instance of the Microsoft Project application
    ms_project = win32com.client.Dispatch('MSProject.Application')

    # Make the application visible (optional)
    ms_project.Visible = True

    # Open a project file
    ms_project.FileOpen('D:\\Manufacturing Resourcing\\Test Folder\\Test.mpp')
    project = ms_project.ActiveProject

    # Constants for TimeScaleData
    pjAssignmentTimescaledWork = 35  
    pjTimescaleDays = 4            

    # Function to print task timephased data
    def print_task_timephased_data(task):
        print(f"Task: {task.Name}")
        if task.Assignments.Count > 0:
            for assignment in task.Assignments:
                print(f"  Assignment: {assignment.ResourceName}")
                try:
                # Get timescale data for each assignment
                    timephased_data = assignment.TimescaleData(task.Start, task.Finish, pjTimescaleDays,         pjAssignmentTimescaledWork)
                    for data in timephased_data:
                        print(f"    Start Date: {data.StartDate}, Work: {data.Value}")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error retrieving timephased data: {e}")

    # Iterate through all tasks and print their timephased data
    for task in project.Tasks:
        if task is not None and task.Start and task.Finish:  # Check to ensure the task is valid and has     start/finish dates
            print_task_timephased_data(task)

    pythoncom.CoUninitialize()


I was able to write to the timeline view in Task Usage using the example  block below. This can be expanded to use larger datasets etc.
import win32com.client
from datetime import datetime

def set_specific_timephased_data():
    try:
        ms_project = win32com.client.Dispatch("MSProject.Application")
        ms_project.Visible = True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error initializing MS Project: {e}")
        return
    try:
        project = ms_project.ActiveProject
    except AttributeError:
        print("No active project found.")
        return

    # Get the first task and its first assignment for demonstration purposes
    if project.Tasks.Count > 0:
        task = project.Tasks.Item(1)
        if task.Assignments.Count > 0:
            assignment = task.Assignments.Item(1)
            
            # Define the start and end dates for the timephased data
            start_date = project.ProjectStart
            end_date = project.ProjectFinish

            # Access the timephased data for work in days
            timescale_data = assignment.TimeScaleData(start_date, end_date, win32com.client.constants.pjAssignmentTimescaledWork, win32com.client.constants.pjTimescaleDays)
            
            # Dictionary of specific dates and corresponding work values (in minutes)
            specific_work_values = {
                datetime(2024, 6, 1): 2 * 60,
                datetime(2024, 6, 2): 1 * 60,
                datetime(2024, 6, 3): 3 * 60,
            }
            
            # Set specific values for specific dates
            for time_value in timescale_data:
                start_date_time = datetime.strptime(time_value.StartDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m-%d')
                end_date_time = datetime.strptime(time_value.EndDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m-%d')
                
                print(f"    TimeScaleValue Object: {time_value}")
                print(f"    Current Work from {start_date_time} to {end_date_time}: {time_value.Value} minutes")
                if start_date_time in specific_work_values:
                    print(f"    Modifying object: {time_value} on {start_date_time}")
                    time_value.Value = specific_work_values[start_date_time]
                    print(f"    Updated Work on {start_date_time} to {time_value.Value} minutes")

            print("Timephased data updated successfully.")

set_specific_timephased_data()

